# Android: Native heap inspection and DDMS

Tags: android, android-ndk, heap-memory, ddms

To get Android native heap inspection working with DDMS, I had found I had to use the standalone DDMS as per ANDROID_HOME/tools/ddms.

After one of the last Android SDK updates, however, there is no such script.  Does anyone know how to do graphical Android native heap inspection now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the workaround appears to be to download an old version of the Android SDK tools where this is not broken from http://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip (replacing "linux" with windows, if on Windows, etc).

This will provide a tools/ddms.bat, etc, that will work properly with the debug malloc instructions.

It appears all subsequent versions of the Android SDK tools have a serious regression in this regard.

Comment: "macosx" for mac. In small letters.

Answer (score 0):

> DDMS is integrated into Android Studio. To use it, launch the Android Device Monitor, and click the DDMS menu button.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html

Comment: Yes, DDMS is integrated in, *but* the instructions on https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-memory for enabling native heap inspection in DDMS do not work on the integrated DDMS.  They only work for the standalone DDMS.  Either (1) the instructions need to be updated to cover the integrated DDMS or (2) I need some way to continue to launch the standalone DDMS.  (1) is clearly ideal...

Comment: you mean you cannot set `native=true`?

Comment: This configuration does not seem to be read by the integrated DDMS -- at least as best I can tell.

Comment: 1) you are **sure** you placed config file in right directory? 2) menu `Window` -> `Settings` -> `General` -> `Show heap status`?

Comment: BTW: you got bad record of not accepting answers to your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4978017/jess-holle

Comment: Show heap status is checked.  That has nothing to do with showing the "Native heap" tab, though.  As for placing ddms.cfg in the right directory, the link is very clear that the location is ~/.android, which is where my ddms.cfg file resides.  Making changes to the DDMS portion of the Android Device Monitor preference settings does make it rather clear that those settings do not go into the ddms.cfg file in ~/.android, though.